# Can an irreducible algebraic function have algebraic values at arguments of transcendence degree $1$ that contain algebraic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, solution-verification

**Can an irreducible algebraic function have algebraic values at arguments of transcendence degree $1$ that contain algebraic numbers?**

$n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge 2$
$A\colon D\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C},(z_1,...,z_n)\mapsto A(z_1,...,z_n)$
$a,a_1,...,a_{n-1}\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$
$t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

My assumption:

$$A(t,a_1,...,a_{n-1})\neq a$$

Is my assumption true?
How can we show that?
$\ $

$$A(t,a_1,...,a_{n-1})=a\tag{1}$$

(1) is an algebraic relation between a transcendental number and algebraic numbers. So (1) is a contradiction, because such relation cannot exist.

We can show this further:

There is a function $A_1\colon D_1\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{C}$, algebraic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, so that

$$t=A_1(a_1,...,a_{n-1}).\tag{2}$$

The left-hand side of (2) is a transcendental number and the right-hand side is an algebraic number. So (2) is a contradiction.

Am I right? Where am I wrong?

Comment: What if $z_1=2\pi$, $z_2=2\pi-1$, $n=1$ and $A(z,w)=z-w$?

Comment: @user10354138 You are right. I mean the case where the argument has only algebraic components and one transcendental component. I edited my question accordingly.